# Listbox VBA No logro establecer la cantidad de columnas

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

[image: Error en la ventana de inmediato]

Tengo una listbox que quiero rellenar con unos datos que tengo en un array, es una array bidimensional.

Son muchas filas pero solo 13 columnas... antes eran 9 y funcionaba bien, ahora queria ampliarla con otros datos para llegar a 13, pero no logro cambiar la cantidad del columnas..

Lo mas extrano es que solo me pasa con esa, tengo otra listbox justo al lado que pude redimensionar con 13 columnas cambiando el columncount en la propiedad del objeto, pero no consigo hacerla con esta.

Para mas cosa rara, cuando pregunto el columncount me dice que efectivamente son 13, pero no puedo acceder mas alla de la columna 9, literalmente el array list solo llega hasta la 9..cosa que no ocurre con la otra listbox..

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour], de esa forma aprenderás a usar el sitio y recibirás tu primera medalla. El código relevante en tu pregunta debe ir en formato de texto y no en imagen. Puedes leer [mcve] para mayor información. Además es necesario que expongas con detalle el error recibido, lo que has intentado y el resultado deseado. Saludos

Comment: Entiendo, voy a leerlo ahora.. muchas gracias.